# Can't specify context for dotnet EF migrations

Tags: entity-framework-core

```
PS C:\Work\Azure\PortalApi> dotnet ef --project .\Portal\Portal.csproj migrations list
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The Entity Framework tools version '6.0.6' is older than that of the runtime '7.0.10'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes. See https://aka.ms/AAc1fbw for more information.
More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.
PS C:\Work\Azure\PortalApi>
```

OK, fair enough, so:

```
PS C:\Work\Azure\PortalApi> dotnet ef --project .\Portal\Portal.csproj --context PortalDbContext migrations list

                     _/\__
               ---==/    \\
         ___  ___   |.    \|\
        | __|| __|  |  )   \\\
        | _| | _|   \_/ |  //|\\
        |___||_|       /   \\\/\\

Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 6.0.6

Usage: dotnet ef [options] [command]

Options:
  --version        Show version information
  -h|--help        Show help information
  -v|--verbose     Show verbose output.
  --no-color       Don't colorize output.
  --prefix-output  Prefix output with level.

Commands:
  database    Commands to manage the database.
  dbcontext   Commands to manage DbContext types.
  migrations  Commands to manage migrations.

Use "dotnet ef [command] --help" for more information about a command.
PS C:\Work\Azure\PortalApi>
```

WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this "Usage" template `[options]` are from the explanation section below it. Everything else is a `[command]`. Each command has a template of `[command] [command-options]`. In your case, `dotnet ef migrations list --project .\Portal\Portal.csproj --context PortalDbContext` should work

```
Usage: dotnet ef [options] [command]

Options: <------ [options]
  --version        Show version information
  ...

Commands: <----- [command], but they also have their own commands and options      
  migrations  Commands to manage migrations.
  ...
```

Also, the entity framework upgrade suggestion that you had in the first step is optional, since it is just a warning

Comment: It appears that the order of the parameters is important. How crap.